# Need to SUM all negative charges and create new column and duplicate with positive charges

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting, accounting

I am trying to create a financial report with one account number that shows a total "debit" (which are positive or >0 amounts) and "credit" (which are negative  or <0) for that particular account number.

Currently I am pulling all transactions for the account number with both negative and positive's in the amount column. I need to split that and SUM all the negatives and create a new column called 'Credits' and SUM all the positives and create a new column called 'Debits'.

I saw one other post on here but that query was not working for me.

```
>     SELECT acc.account, acc.account_ty, coa.DESCR, dis.Amount, acc.create_dt, 
>     FROM GL_COA_ACCOUNT acc
>     JOIN GL_COA_CHART coa
>     ON acc.account = coa.account
>     JOIN AR_GL_DISTRIB dis
>     ON dis.GLCHART_SERNO = coa.GLCHART_SERNO
>     JOIN AR_RCT_LEDGER led
>     ON led.DISTRIB_SERNO = dis.distrib_serno
>     JOIN AR_RCT_INVHDR inv
>     ON led.invoice_num = inv.invoice_num


**Account account_ty   DESCR                               Amount create_dt DEBITS CREDITS NET AMOUNT**
XXX09   ASSET       XXX09-00-000-00  A/R Membership Dues   -55  09-AUG-16
XXX23   LIABILITY   XXX23-00-000-00  Checks / Cash Clearing 55  07-SEP-16
XXX09   ASSET       XXX09-00-000-00  A/R Membership Dues    55  09-AUG-16
XXX02   INCOME      XXX02-01-000-00  Predoctoral Student D -55  07-SEP-16
XXX09   ASSET       XXX09-00-000-00  A/R Membership Dues   -55  09-AUG-16
XXX23   LIABILITY   XXX23-00-000-00  Checks / Cash Clearing 55  07-SEP-16
XXX09   ASSET       XXX09-00-000-00  A/R Membership Dues    55  09-AUG-16
```

Comment: Please don't remove all your code from the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is *conditional aggregation*:

```
select ......,   sum(case when amount < 0 then amount end) as credits,
                 sum(case when amount > 0 then amount end) as debits
from   ......
group by account_number
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest something like that:

```
SELECT account,
       sum((amount>0)*amount) as debit, 
       sum((amount<0)*amount) as credit
FROM table
GROUP BY account
```

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to code here. It looks like C code, where (amount>0) is a numeric expression with values 0 and 1. It doesn't work that way in SQL - certainly not in Oracle SQL.

Comment: thats a boolean value, which is 1 when True and 0 when false

Comment: I will only say it one more time: **It doesn't work that way in SQL - certainly not in Oracle SQL**. Even in SQL Standard, BOOLEAN (which Oracle does not implement to begin with) is a different data type from NUMBER.

Comment: try it here: SELECT (CustomerID>20)*CustomerID 
FROM Customers

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in

Comment: No. You should try it, in an Oracle database.

Comment: I have updated my post with the results and query hopefully that helps

Answer (score 0):

**Create an Expression Which Checks for Sign of Amount (and NULLS) and Assigns a Non-NULL Value and Sums**

I just make sure that my expression is non-NULL (all records have a non-NULL numeric assignment) and then I sum.

Being primarily an Oracle SQL developer, I am biased towards Oracle functions such as `decode` and `sign`.

```
     SCOTT@dev>WITH test_data AS (
  2      SELECT
  3          4.32 amount, '100' account
  4      FROM
  5          dual
  6      UNION ALL
  7      SELECT 3.23, '100'
  8      FROM
  9          dual
 10      UNION ALL
 11      SELECT
 12          -3.22, '100'
 13      FROM
 14          dual
 15      UNION ALL
 16      SELECT
 17          -4.22, '100'
 18      FROM
 19          dual
 20      UNION ALL
 21      SELECT
 22          4.22, '200'
 23      FROM
 24          dual
 25      UNION ALL
 26      SELECT
 27          0, '200'
 28      FROM
 29          dual
 30      UNION ALL
 31      SELECT
 32          NULL, '200'
 33      FROM
 34          dual
 35  ) SELECT
 36      account,
 37      SUM(DECODE( sign(nvl( amount, 0) ), 1, amount, 0) ) debits,
 38      SUM(DECODE( sign(nvl( amount, 0) ), -1, amount, 0) ) credits
 39  FROM
 40      test_data
 41  GROUP BY
 42      account;
ACCOUNT  DEBITS  CREDITS  
100      7.55    -7.44    
200      4.22    0
```